# Get count for different tables in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is wrong with:

```
select count (a.*, b.*)
from tableA a, tableB b
where a.x = 'blah'
and b.x = 'blah'
```

I keep getting the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '*'.

I have a bunch of table names to select from so wanted to use table name aliases? Any help appreciated: I'm not very good with sql.

Comment: count(*) will do fine here! Or perhaps count(a.columnname).

Comment: should've made my question clearer, i have a bunch of tables to select from. updating my question to show this...

Comment: Yeah--that's just plain not going to work.  Please explain what result you are trying to get.  A sample table of results will be helpful.

Comment: select count( * ) from tableA union all select count( * ) from tableB etc

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx

Comment: @samyi i didn't know 'count over(...)' existed! tbh i selected the answer below because it's the only one i understand. I don't know how optimal/concise it is though... i am counting values from 4 tables :( Thanks everyone for all the help and pointers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use multiply arguments in `COUNT`. In your case you are asking to give you count of `a.col1, a.col2, a.col3...` `COUNT` expects just 1 argument. The only exception is `*` in that case it understands that it is supposed to calculate all the records from the table.

If you would like to calculate all the records from a, then do something like `COUNT(a.id)`. If you want to calculate unique records of a table, then do `COUNT(distinct a.id)`.

If you want to calculate all the records from `a` and `b` tables, then you can do `COUNT(a.id) as quantityOfAtable, COUNT(b.id) as quantityOfBtable`. Or you can sum them `COUNT(a.id) + COUNT(b.id)`.

One more thing you need to know about `COUNT` that it is counting only the `NOT NULL` rows. So, if you are using `LEFT JOIN` or the column that can be NULL then it will just calculate the amount of the records where this column is `NOT NULL`. Of course, you can use `DISTINCT` to calculate unique records as well.

Answer (score 0):

- `COUNT()` function takes `only one parameter`.

**count (a.*)**: means `count(a.field1,a.field2,a.field3,....)` which is `invalid`.

you have to use **count(*)**: means `count all` .

Answer (score 0):

You should be using JOIN syntax here:

```
select count(*)
from tableA a
inner join tableB b
  on a.x = b.x
where a.x = 'blah'
```